# What does ?~> meaning in the scala programming language?

Tags: scala

I met with the below statements in a scala code

```
val stage = stage1 ?~> stage2 ?~> stage3 ~> stage4
```

Can anyone please explain the meaning of the **?~>** and how these statements will be evaluated.

Comment: Where did you see this code? Akka by any chance? I am not sure this is in the standard library

Comment: Codebase usage scala version `2.12.15`

Comment: What other libraries are you `import`ing into the code?

Answer (score 3):

An infix operation `a op b` is compiler shorthand for `a.op(b)`. So that code is directly equivalent to

```
((stage1.?~>(stage2)).?~>(stage3)).~>(stage4)
```

which is evaluated like this:

```
val t1 = stage1.?~>(stage2)
val t2 = t1.?~>(stage3)
val result = t2.~>(stage4)
```

`?~>` is a method of the object `stage1` that returns an object that has a `?~>` method that returns an object with a `~>` method.

What it actually does depends on what library you are using and the type of the `stage` objects.